# Want my Button to remain dark when clicked

Tags: css, gravityforms

For the form on this page: http://16q.47c.myftpupload.com/get-a-quote/
I want to make the buttons "Round Trip" / "One Way", when clicked, keep their red background.

I used Gravity Forms to build the form and customized the CSS to make it look that way. Those 2 "buttons" are actually Radio Buttons.

I don't have access to the HTML so a CSS-only fix would be great (unless you know how to edit the HTML of a Gravity Form)!

Appreciate the help in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the radio button get selected when you click the button, you can use a checkbox hack(radio button hack)

```
input[name="input_11"]:checked + #label_2_11_0,
input[name="input_11"]:checked + #label_2_11_1 {
  background-color: #8d181b !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

this will select the next sibling with label tag of a input with name="input_11" and change it's background color. I'm using name="input_11" because that's what the radio button had in your website.

Comment: Only thing is now the text color is also red...how can I make it white?

Comment: np glad to help, you might want to clean the css abit tho, it's hard to make change in the future with so many !important

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add `:focus` to whichever css class you have used for those radio buttons, follow the example given below,

```css
.btnbtn{
background-color:blue;
}

.btnbtn:focus{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<button class="btnbtn">abcd</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This should work Perfectly.

Comment: Thanks I added 
`#label_2_11_0:focus { 
 background-color: red !important;
}`

to my CSS but it didn't work...any idea why? Maybe I'm targeting the wrong item?

Answer (score 0):

If you can have access to the CSS, try adding the radio button `:checked` option and have the `background-color` to red.

Just see the code snippet and try to do.

```css
/*https://codepen.io/kevinfarrugia/pen/pJZezE*/

.hungry .selection {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.hungry .selection label {
  display: inline-block;
  width:8em;
  background-color: #42b4d6;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hungry .selection label:hover {
  background-color: #5fc0dc;
}

.hungry .selection input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.hungry .selection input[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background-color: #f1592a;
}
```

```html
<div class="hungry">
  <div class="selection">
    <input id="pizza" name="hungry" type="radio">
    <label for="pizza">Pizza</label>
  </div>
  <div class="selection">
    <input id="burger" name="hungry" type="radio">
    <label for="burger">Burger + Chips</label>
  </div>
  <div class="selection">
    <input id="bread" name="hungry" type="radio">
    <label for="bread">Hobz biz-zejt!</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks I added `#label_2_11_0:checked { background-color: red !important; }` to my CSS but it didn't work...any idea why? Maybe I'm targeting the wrong item?

Comment: @Rhami try #choice_2_11_1:checked {background-color:red !important;} it might work I guess